# Using plugin in PHPfox

Tags: plugins, phpfox

Can anyone tell me why this call `{plugin call='video.template_block_entry_1'}`  is made in `phpfox\module\video\template\default\block\entry.html.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

That is a hook, it allow other module can insert their code to this file.
Example, in other module, we can create a new file name: video.template_block_entry_1.php in module/[module_name]/include/plugin/
with contain:

```
<?php echo "Hello world";
```

More text hello world will include to entry.html.php